# Is there a very fast way to pad a Scipy CSR column matrix with zeros on either side?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

For instance, I have a column matrix A as follows :

```
A:
[1,
 2, 
 3, 
 4,]
```

I need to be able to pad x and y number of zeros to the top and bottom really fast. Here let x = 2, and y = 3. so the resultant matrix B after the padding will be :

```
B:
[0,
 0,
 1,
 2, 
 3, 
 4,
 0,
 0,
 0]
```

Now the issue is that these are VERY large column matrices, and millions of them, and I know that in the CSR representation I should just change the matrix shape and indices. Could anyone help?

Comment: what is shape of array? You need to add `0` for all columns?

Comment: With a (n,1) shape, a `csr` takes up more space than the equivalent dense array.

Answer (score 2):

Padding just `A.indptr` with [`numpy.pad`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.pad.html) should be fairly fast:

```
B = csr_matrix((A.data, A.indices, numpy.pad(A.indptr, (x, y), "edge")))
```